# Convert JSON array to an HTML table in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, html-table

Is there a really easy way I can take an array of JSON objects and turn it into an HTML table, excluding a few fields?  Or am I going to have to do this manually?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm not sure if is this that you want but there is [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/). It can receive JSON and make a grid.

Comment: Another vote for jqGrid - really easy to implement, has great documentation and examples, and cuts down on a lot of the work for you.

Comment: jqGrid looks very promising!

Comment: Note that jqGrid is a commercial product with a non-trivial license cost.

Answer (score 87):

Using jQuery will make this simpler.

The following code will take an array of arrays and store convert them into rows and cells.

```
$.getJSON(url , function(data) {
    var tbl_body = "";
    var odd_even = false;
    $.each(data, function() {
        var tbl_row = "";
        $.each(this, function(k , v) {
            tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
        });
        tbl_body += "<tr class=\""+( odd_even ? "odd" : "even")+"\">"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
        odd_even = !odd_even;               
    });
    $("#target_table_id tbody").html(tbl_body);
});
```

You could add a check for the keys you want to exclude by adding something like

```
var expected_keys = { key_1 : true, key_2 : true, key_3 : false, key_4 : true };
```

at the start of the getJSON callback function and adding:

```
if ( ( k in expected_keys ) && expected_keys[k] ) {
...
}
```

around the tbl_row += line.

Edit: Was assigning a null variable previously

Edit: Version based on [Timmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265521/timmmm)'s [injection-free](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27821863/1272141) contribution.

```
$.getJSON(url , function(data) {
    var tbl_body = document.createElement("tbody");
    var odd_even = false;
    $.each(data, function() {
        var tbl_row = tbl_body.insertRow();
        tbl_row.className = odd_even ? "odd" : "even";
        $.each(this, function(k , v) {
            var cell = tbl_row.insertCell();
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(v.toString()));
        });        
        odd_even = !odd_even;               
    });
    $("#target_table_id").append(tbl_body);   //DOM table doesn't have .appendChild
});
```

Comment: I am having a hard time controlling the order of the columns

Comment: Just saw this. How would I write it so the `<tr>` alternated between having a class of even or odd?

Comment: The order of the columns will depend on the order they appear in the source data.

I've added in a simple odd/even alternator to the OP.

Comment: Be aware this is vulnerable to script injection. I.e. don't use it with user-generated content.

Comment: Cheers Timmmm, I've added an (untested) DOM version, based on your example, at the end of the post.

Comment: On the second line, it's important that the element being inserted be `'table'`.  The `insertRow` call doesn't work with `'tbody'` as it appears above.

Comment: You should use *$("#target_table_id").append(tbl_body);*  instead of     *$("#target_table_id").appendChild(tbl_body);* since jQuery object only expose an append function.

Answer (score 15):

Make a HTML Table from a JSON array of Objects by extending $ as shown below

```
$.makeTable = function (mydata) {
    var table = $('<table border=1>');
    var tblHeader = "<tr>";
    for (var k in mydata[0]) tblHeader += "<th>" + k + "</th>";
    tblHeader += "</tr>";
    $(tblHeader).appendTo(table);
    $.each(mydata, function (index, value) {
        var TableRow = "<tr>";
        $.each(value, function (key, val) {
            TableRow += "<td>" + val + "</td>";
        });
        TableRow += "</tr>";
        $(table).append(TableRow);
    });
    return ($(table));
};
```

and use as follows:

```
var mydata = eval(jdata);
var table = $.makeTable(mydata);
$(table).appendTo("#TableCont");
```

where TableCont is some div

Answer (score 9):

Pure HTML way, not vulnerable like the others AFAIK:

```
// Function to create a table as a child of el.
// data must be an array of arrays (outer array is rows).
function tableCreate(el, data)
{
    var tbl  = document.createElement("table");
    tbl.style.width  = "70%";

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
    {
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        for(var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j)
        {
            var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i][j].toString()));
        }
    }
    el.appendChild(tbl);
}
```

Example usage:

```
$.post("/whatever", { somedata: "test" }, null, "json")
.done(function(data) {
    rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Results.length; ++i)
    {
        cells = [];
        cells.push(data.Results[i].A);
        cells.push(data.Results[i].B);
        rows.push(cells);
    }
    tableCreate($("#results")[0], rows);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Converting a 2D JavaScript array to an HTML table

To turn a 2D JavaScript array into an HTML table, you really need but a little bit of code :

```js
function arrayToTable(tableData) {
    var table = $('<table></table>');
    $(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
        var row = $('<tr></tr>');
        $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
            row.append($('<td>'+cellData+'</td>'));
        });
        table.append(row);
    });
    return table;
}

$('body').append(arrayToTable([
    ["John","Slegers",34],
    ["Tom","Stevens",25],
    ["An","Davies",28],
    ["Miet","Hansen",42],
    ["Eli","Morris",18]
]));
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

#### Loading a JSON file

If you want to load your 2D array from a JSON file, you'll also need a little bit of Ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $('body').append(arrayToTable(data));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

For very advanced JSON objects to HTML tables you can try [My jQuery Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/7og5348w/3/) that is based on this [closed thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table).

```
var myList=[{"name": "abc","age": 50},{"name": {"1": "piet","2": "jan","3": "klaas"},"age": "25","hobby": "watching tv"},{"name": "xyz","hobby": "programming","subtable": [{"a": "a","b": "b"},{"a": "a","b": "b"}]}];

// Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data from Ivy restful service.
 function buildHtmlTable() {
      addTable(myList, $("#excelDataTable"));
 }

function addTable(list, appendObj) {
    var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(list, appendObj);

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var row$ = $('<tr/>');
        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {
            var cellValue = list[i][columns[colIndex]];

            if (cellValue == null) {
                cellValue = "";
            }

            if (cellValue.constructor === Array)
            {
                $a = $('<td/>');
                row$.append($a);
                addTable(cellValue, $a);

            } else if (cellValue.constructor === Object)
            {

                var array = $.map(cellValue, function (value, index) {
                    return [value];
                });

                $a = $('<td/>');
                row$.append($a);
                addObject(array, $a);

            } else {
                row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
            }
        }
        appendObj.append(row$);
    }
}


function addObject(list, appendObj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var row$ = $('<tr/>');

        var cellValue = list[i];

        if (cellValue == null) {
            cellValue = "";
        }

        if (cellValue.constructor === Array)
        {
            $a = $('<td/>');
            row$.append($a);
            addTable(cellValue, $a);

        } else if (cellValue.constructor === Object)
        {

            var array = $.map(cellValue, function (value, index) {
                return [value];
            });

            $a = $('<td/>');
            row$.append($a);
            addObject(array, $a);

        } else {
            row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
        }
        appendObj.append(row$);
    }
}

// Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
// Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
// all records
function addAllColumnHeaders(list, appendObj)
{
    var columnSet = [];
    var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var rowHash = list[i];
        for (var key in rowHash) {
            if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {
                columnSet.push(key);
                headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
            }
        }
    }
    appendObj.append(headerTr$);

    return columnSet;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One simple way of doing this is:

```js
var data = [{
  "Total": 34,
  "Version": "1.0.4",
  "Office": "New York"
}, {
  "Total": 67,
  "Version": "1.1.0",
  "Office": "Paris"
}];

drawTable(data);

function drawTable(data) {

  // Get Table headers and print
  var head = $("<tr />")
  $("#DataTable").append(head);
  for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(data[0]).length; j++) {
    head.append($("<th>" + Object.keys(data[0])[j] + "</th>"));
  }

  // Print the content of rows in DataTable
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    drawRow(data[i]);
  }

}

function drawRow(rowData) {
  var row = $("<tr />")
  $("#DataTable").append(row);
  row.append($("<td>" + rowData["Total"] + "</td>"));
  row.append($("<td>" + rowData["Version"] + "</td>"));
  row.append($("<td>" + rowData["Office"] + "</td>"));
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="DataTable"></table>
```

Comment: Drawrow function can be made generic as below : function drawRow(rowData) {
           var row = $("<tr />")
           $("#DataTable").append(row);
           $.each(rowData,function(k,v) {
            row.append($("<td>" + v + "</td>"));
           });

}

Answer (score 2):

You could use a jQuery plugin that accepts JSON data to fill a table.
[jsonTable](https://github.com/omkarkhair/jsonTable)

Answer (score 2):

I found a duplicate over here: [Convert json data to a html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table)

Well, there are many plugins exists, including commercial one (Make this as commercial project?! Kinda overdone... but you can checkout over here: https://github.com/alfajango/jquery-dynatable)

This one has more fork: https://github.com/afshinm/Json-to-HTML-Table

```
//Example data, Object 
var objectArray = [{
    "Total": "34",
    "Version": "1.0.4",
    "Office": "New York"
}, {
    "Total": "67",
    "Version": "1.1.0",
    "Office": "Paris"
}];

//Example data, Array
var stringArray = ["New York", "Berlin", "Paris", "Marrakech", "Moscow"];

//Example data, nested Object. This data will create nested table also.
var nestedTable = [{
    key1: "val1",
    key2: "val2",
    key3: {
        tableId: "tblIdNested1",
        tableClassName: "clsNested",
        linkText: "Download",
        data: [{
            subkey1: "subval1",
            subkey2: "subval2",
            subkey3: "subval3"
        }]
    }
}];
```

Apply the code

```
//Only first parameter is required
var jsonHtmlTable = ConvertJsonToTable(objectArray, 'jsonTable', null, 'Download');
```

Or you might want to checkout this jQuery plugins as well: https://github.com/jongha/jquery-jsontotable

I think jongha's plugins is easier to use

```
<div id="jsontotable" class="jsontotable"></div>

var data = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]];
$.jsontotable(data, { id: '#jsontotable', header: false });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you accept using another *jQuery* dependent tool, I would recommend using [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/). Then you will not need to write HTML or any other DOM generating code, while maintaining great flexibility regarding the formatting and processing of the table data.

[image]

For another working example using *Node*, you can look at the [MMM-Tabulator](https://github.com/E3V3A/MMM-Tabulator) demo project.

Answer (score 1):

with pure jquery:

```
window.jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxUrl,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {

        var odd_even = false;
        var response = JSON.parse(data);

        var head = "<thead class='thead-inverse'><tr>";
        $.each(response[0], function (k, v) {
            head = head + "<th scope='row'>" + k.toString() + "</th>";
        })
        head = head + "</thead></tr>";
        $(table).append(head);//append header
       var body="<tbody><tr>";
        $.each(response, function () {
            body=body+"<tr>";
            $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                body=body +"<td>"+v.toString()+"</td>";                                        
            }) 
            body=body+"</tr>";               
        })
        body=body +"</tbody>";
        $(table).append(body);//append body
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.responsetext);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with Javascript+Jquery as below.
If you want to exclude some column, just write an if statement inside the for loops to skip those columns. Hope this helps!

```js
//Sample JSON 2D array
var json = [{
  "Total": "34",
  "Version": "1.0.4",
  "Office": "New York"
}, {
  "Total": "67",
  "Version": "1.1.0",
  "Office": "Paris"
}];

// Get Table headers and print
for (var k = 0; k < Object.keys(json[0]).length; k++) {
  $('#table_head').append('<td>' + Object.keys(json[0])[k] + '</td>');
}

// Get table body and print
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(json).length; i++) {
  $('#table_content').append('<tr>');
  for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(json[0]).length; j++) {
    $('#table_content').append('<td>' + json[i][Object.keys(json[0])[j]] + '</td>');
  }
  $('#table_content').append('</tr>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr id="table_head">

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table_content">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified a bit code of @Dr.sai 's code. Hope this will be useful.

```
(function ($) {
    /**
     * data - array of record
     * hidecolumns, array of fields to hide
     * usage : $("selector").generateTable(json, ['field1', 'field5']);
     */
    'use strict';
    $.fn.generateTable = function (data, hidecolumns) {
        if ($.isArray(data) === false) {
            console.log('Invalid Data');
            return;
        }
        var container = $(this),
            table = $('<table>'),
            tableHead = $('<thead>'),       
            tableBody = $('<tbody>'),       
            tblHeaderRow = $('<tr>');       

        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            var tableRow = $('<tr>').addClass(index%2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd');      
            $.each(value, function (key, val) {
                if (index == 0 && $.inArray(key, hidecolumns) <= -1 ) { 
                    var theaddata = $('<th>').text(key);
                    tblHeaderRow.append(theaddata); 
                }
                if ($.inArray(key, hidecolumns) <= -1 ) { 
                    var tbodydata = $('<td>').text(val);
                    tableRow.append(tbodydata);     
                }
            });
            $(tableBody).append(tableRow);  
        });
        $(tblHeaderRow).appendTo(tableHead);
        tableHead.appendTo(table);      
        tableBody.appendTo(table);
        $(this).append(table);    
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Hoping this will be helpful to hide some columns too.
[Link to file](https://gist.github.com/smartameer/fe3b13f6252252e32fd9#file-generate-table-js)

Answer (score 0):

Pivoted single-row view with headers on the left based on @Dr.sai's  answer above.

Injection prevented by jQuery's .text method

```
$.makeTable = function (mydata) {
    var table = $('<table>');
    $.each(mydata, function (index, value) {
        // console.log('index '+index+' value '+value);
        $(table).append($('<tr>'));
        $(table).append($('<th>').text(index));
        $(table).append($('<td>').text(value));
    });
    return ($(table));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a HTML Table from a JSON array of Objects by extending $ as shown below

```
$.makeTable = function (mydata, cssClass) {
    if (!cssClass) cssClass = "table table-bordered table-stripped table-dark"
    var table = $('<table class="' + cssClass + '">');
    var tblHeader = "<thead><tr>";
    for (var k in mydata[0]) tblHeader += "<th>" + k + "</th>";
    tblHeader += "</tr></thead>";
    $(tblHeader).appendTo(table);
    var TableRow = "<tbody>";
    $.each(mydata, function (index, value) {
        TableRow += "<tr id=_ID_>".replace("_ID_", value.name);
        $.each(value, function (key, val) {
            TableRow += "<td>" + val + "</td>";
        });
        TableRow += "</tr>";
    });
    TableRow += "</tbody>";
    $(table).append(TableRow);
    return ($(table));
};
```

Usage as Below

```
var EmployeeArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    let emp = {};
    emp.name = "Varsha_" + i;
    emp.age = Math.round((Math.random() * 100 + 10)) * 3
    EmployeeArr.push(emp);
}
var table = $.makeTable(EmployeeArr );
$(table).appendTo("#TableCont");
```

where TableCont is some div

Answer (score 0):

In case you want customize the table header and even customize rendering . . .

```
$.makeTable = function (mydata, cssClass, HeaderMapping, callback) {
if (!cssClass) cssClass = "display table table-bordered table-secondary table-hover table-stripped table-light";
var table = $('<table border="1" id="example" class="' + cssClass + '">');
var tblHeader = '<thead ><tr class="table-warning">';
for (var k in mydata[0]) {
    if (HeaderMapping) tblHeader += "<th>" + HeaderMapping[k] + "</th>";
    else tblHeader += "<th>" + k + "</th>";
}
tblHeader += "</tr></thead>";
$(tblHeader).appendTo(table);
var TableRow = "<tbody>";
$.each(mydata, function (index, value) {
    TableRow += "<tr id=_ID_>".replace("_ID_", value.name);
    $.each(value, function (key, val) {
        if (callback) TableRow += "<td>" + callback(key, val, value) + "</td>";
        else TableRow += "<td>" + val + "</td>";
    });
    TableRow += "</tr>";
});
TableRow += "</tbody>";
var tblFooter = "<tfoot><tr>";
for (var k in mydata[0]) tblFooter += "<th>" + k + "</th>";
tblFooter += "</tr></tfoot>";
TableRow += tblFooter;
$(table).append(TableRow);
return ($(table));};
```

usage

```
var EmployeeArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    let emp = {};
    emp.name = "Varsha_" + i;
    emp.age = Math.round((Math.random() * 100 + 10)) * 3
    EmployeeArr.push(emp);
}
let htmlTable = $.makeTable(EmployeeArr , 
        {
            name:"What's in a Name",
            age: "My Age"
        }, 
        (key, val, value) => {
                switch (key) {
                    case "name": {
                        return "<a target='_blank' href='" + config.contextPath + "Home/DownloadPicture?FileName=" + val + "' >Download Image</a>"
                    }
                    case "age": return val + "Years";                        
                }                    
                return val;
            })
```

Answer (score -1):

A still shorter way

```
$.makeTable = function (mydata) {
            if (mydata.length <= 0) return "";
           return $('<table border=1>').append("<tr>" + $.map(mydata[0], function (val, key) {
                return "<th>" + key + "</th>";
            }).join("\n") + "</tr>").append($.map(mydata, function (index, value) {
                return "<tr>" + $.map(index, function (val, key) {
                    return "<td>" + val + "</td>";
                }).join("\n") + "</tr>";
            }).join("\n"));
        };
```

Comment: Vulnerable to HTML/script injection.