# Convert json data to a html table

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

Is there any jQuery or javascript library that generates a dynamic table given json data?
I don't want to define the columns, the library should read the keys in the json hash and generate columns.

Of course, I can myself iterate through the json data and generate the html table. I just want to know if any such library exists which I can simply reuse.

Comment: I think http://www.trirand.com/blog/ is what you are looking for. It takes JSON and converts it into a grid.

Comment: Well, Thanks for the replies. But to suffice my requirements I wrote one for myself. http://jsfiddle.net/manishmmulani/7MRx6/

Comment: You can also use this simple project on Github : [Json-To-HTML-Table](https://github.com/afshinm/Json-to-HTML-Table)

Comment: More easily in 2020, just use https://github.com/arters/Convert-json-data-to-a-html-template

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Thanks all for your replies. [I wrote one myself.](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmmulani/7MRx6) Please note that this uses jQuery.

Code snippet:

```js
var myList = [
  { "name": "abc", "age": 50 },
  { "age": "25", "hobby": "swimming" },
  { "name": "xyz", "hobby": "programming" }
];

// Builds the HTML Table out of myList.
function buildHtmlTable(selector) {
  var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList, selector);

  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    var row$ = $('<tr/>');
    for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {
      var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];
      if (cellValue == null) cellValue = "";
      row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
    }
    $(selector).append(row$);
  }
}

// Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
// Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
// all records.
function addAllColumnHeaders(myList, selector) {
  var columnSet = [];
  var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    var rowHash = myList[i];
    for (var key in rowHash) {
      if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {
        columnSet.push(key);
        headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
      }
    }
  }
  $(selector).append(headerTr$);

  return columnSet;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onLoad="buildHtmlTable('#excelDataTable')">
  <table id="excelDataTable" border="1">
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: `function addAllColumnHeaders(myList)` - is wrong. should be `function addAllColumnHeaders(myList,selector)`. BTW this works perfect!!

Comment: If you plan to use [https://datatables.net/] make sure that you put your rows in **<thead/>** tag in _addAllColumnHeaders_ function and **<tbody/>** tag in _buildHtmlTable_ function.

Comment: A simple and easy way: https://github.com/arters/Convert-json-data-to-a-html-template/

Comment: @Cyval Maybe this is help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/4674199

Answer (score 84):

I have rewritten your code in vanilla-js, using DOM methods to prevent html injection.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7MRx6/338/)

```js
var _table_ = document.createElement('table'),
  _tr_ = document.createElement('tr'),
  _th_ = document.createElement('th'),
  _td_ = document.createElement('td');

// Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data from Ivy restful service.
function buildHtmlTable(arr) {
  var table = _table_.cloneNode(false),
    columns = addAllColumnHeaders(arr, table);
  for (var i = 0, maxi = arr.length; i < maxi; ++i) {
    var tr = _tr_.cloneNode(false);
    for (var j = 0, maxj = columns.length; j < maxj; ++j) {
      var td = _td_.cloneNode(false);
      var cellValue = arr[i][columns[j]];
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i][columns[j]] || ''));
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  return table;
}

// Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
// Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
// all records
function addAllColumnHeaders(arr, table) {
  var columnSet = [],
    tr = _tr_.cloneNode(false);
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    for (var key in arr[i]) {
      if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key) && columnSet.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        columnSet.push(key);
        var th = _th_.cloneNode(false);
        th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(key));
        tr.appendChild(th);
      }
    }
  }
  table.appendChild(tr);
  return columnSet;
}

document.body.appendChild(buildHtmlTable([{
    "name": "abc",
    "age": 50
  },
  {
    "age": "25",
    "hobby": "swimming"
  },
  {
    "name": "xyz",
    "hobby": "programming"
  }
]));
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this work with a nested json object?

Comment: @JanacMeena I think you would need n-dimensional tables for that.

Comment: That's true. Tables within tables. Also, I discovered zoomable treemaps which allow for nested json

Comment: This same function but returning a pivoted table, would be beautifull

Comment: How does one add data for the table? In the demo it's added as the directly as the parameter to the function: 
document.body.appendChild(buildHtmlTable([
    {"name" : "abc", "age" : 50},
    {"age" : "25", "hobby" : "swimming"},
    {"name" : "xyz", "hobby" : "programming"}
])); My data works when I add it like that also. But when I put that data in a variable, it isn't working. Ideas?

Comment: @Shai use JSON.parse(yourVariable) and send it to buldHTMLTable

Comment: Thank you for this code--very nicely written! I slightly modified it to include thead and tbody. It is more semantic and makes the table compatible with third-party formatters such as FooTable: http://jsfiddle.net/1cdL98sk/

Comment: The post is so old and so good written in vanilla js. I add a second parameter for the id,with `table.id=id` in `buildHtmlTable(arr,id)`

Answer (score 15):

Check out <s>[JSON2HTML](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/json2html)</s> http://json2html.com/ plugin for jQuery. It allows you to specify a transform that would convert your JSON object to HTML template. Use builder on http://json2html.com/ to get json transform object for any desired html template. In your case, it would be a table with row having following transform.

**Example:**

```
var transform = {"tag":"table", "children":[
    {"tag":"tbody","children":[
        {"tag":"tr","children":[
            {"tag":"td","html":"${name}"},
            {"tag":"td","html":"${age}"}
        ]}
    ]}
]};

var data = [
    {'name':'Bob','age':40},
    {'name':'Frank','age':15},
    {'name':'Bill','age':65},
    {'name':'Robert','age':24}
];

$('#target_div').html(json2html.transform(data,transform));
```

Comment: figured I'd update the link here to http://json2html.com

Comment: You need [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json2html) node-json2html in order to work on server side NodeJS

Answer (score 14):

You can use simple jQuery jPut plugin

http://plugins.jquery.com/jput/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var json = [{"name": "name1","email":"email1@domain.com"},{"name": "name2","link":"email2@domain.com"}];
//while running this code the template will be appended in your div with json data
$("#tbody").jPut({
    jsonData:json,
    //ajax_url:"youfile.json",  if you want to call from a json file
    name:"tbody_template",
});

});
</script>   

<table jput="t_template">
 <tbody jput="tbody_template">
     <tr>
         <td>{{name}}</td>
         <td>{{email}}</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<table>
 <tbody id="tbody">
 </tbody>
</table>
```