# read json using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, xmlhttprequest

I am sending some request on a server and it's reply me this:

```
{
    "count": 100,
    "entries": [
        {
            "id": 7563,
            "application": "my-app",
            "user": "admin",
            "time": "2012-10-10T11:32:09.324+07:00",
            "values": {
                "/my-app/name": "4d79f56b-1a20-4b25-bff6-b5f1d7253790"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 7561,
            "application": "my-app",
            "user": "admin",
            "time": "2012-10-10T11:32:08.687+07:00",
            "values": {
                "/my-app/name": "4d79f56b-1a20-4b25-bff6-b5f1d7253790"
            }
        }
}
```

I tried, but nothing seems to working for me!

```
 var my_JSON_object = {};
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

 my_JSON_object = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

 xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
 xmlhttp.sand();
```

Everything is fine. but **values** return null.
Any help would be appreciated!

[[my code]](https://gist.github.com/3864263)

Comment: This may help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table

Answer (score 3):

correct your code:

```js
 xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
 xmlhttp.send();

 //get response after sending request
 my_JSON_object = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 alert(my_JSON_object.entries.id);
```

Comment: Available. but `alert(my_JSON_object.entries[0].values)` it's return **null**

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is just to use jQuery to do it:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    alert(data.count);
    ...
});
```