# Using JSON data in HTML table

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. In one of my projects, I want to use `Ajax` for `searching data`. My plan is, user will input parameters/fields to search specific data. After they input data, an `Ajax request` will be sent to the controller and the controller will return the result data and the result data will be shown in a `specific div`.

So, first I tried to return the result in normal `php array` and show that array in a `table`. But, it didn't work. Then I got a suggestion to use `JSON` as the return data type. Now I am trying to use it.

But, I don't know yet how to show `JSON` data/array in a `table`. So, can you please give me an example of how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Take a look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table

Answer (score 0):

Well you will need to do few steps.

- Create a empty layout that will only print the json.
- Concatinate the data into a variable and then at the end of the concatication. Use json_encode
- And echo the JSON string.
- Then you can simply parse the value and show the results on the AJax requesting page.