# How to print json values to HTML table

Tags: html, json, ajax

Below is ajax function which im using and alert output of the data

ajax function:

```
      function load(userType){
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "load.html",
                data: "userType=" + userType,
                success: function(response){
                    alert(response);              
                },
          });   
       }
```

alert output:

```
[{
    "userId":1,
    "email":"jay@gmail.com",
    "mobile":"9900082195",
    "gender":"male",
    "qualification":"1",
    "dob":"1990-01-01",

    "login":{
        "loginId":1,
        "userName":"Jay",
        "password":"Jay",
    }
}]
```

how can i print the above json alert output to html table??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert json data to a html table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table)