# How to print JSON response from JAVA method to HTML Table?

Tags: java, html, json, jsp

I have a jsp code, where I fetch some JSON data from JAVA Class file. [Basically openfire users]

Now I get the data successfully, but I want to show this data in HTML table format.

How do I Do this ?

My JSP Code :

```
<%@ page language="java" import="prov.*, java.util.*, java.io.*,java.text.*" contentType="text/html"%>
<%@ page errorPage="error.jsp" %>
<%

Openfire tc = new Openfire();

tc.getUsers("192.168.50.218","epvFjHq5RHA614C7");

out.println("Data Is As Below : " + tc.getUsers("192.168.50.218","epvFjHq5RHA614C7"));

%>
```

And I get Response from the JAVA Class method like this :

```
[{"username":"abcd","name":"","properties":null},{"username":"admin","email":"admin@example.com","name":"Administrator","properties":null},{"username":"bizdd456d454mnc","email":"bizMNC@bizrtc.com","name":"bidzMNC","properties":null},{"username":"bizddd454mnc","email":"bizMNC@bizrtc.com","name":"bidzMNC","properties":null},{"username":"bizmnc","email":"admin@example.com","name":"511515151515151","properties":{"property":[{"@key":"console.order","@value":"session-summary=1"},{"@key":"console.rows_per_page","@value":"user-summary=8"}]}},{"username":"dhaval","email":"dhaval@bizrtc.com","name":"dhaval","properties":null},{"username":"keyur","email":"keyur@bizrtc.com","name":"keyur","properties":null},{"username":"minz","email":"bizMNC@bizrtc.com","name":"bidzMNC","properties":null},{"username":"patel","email":"rau@example.com","name":"patelbhai","properties":{"property":[{"@key":"console.order","@value":"session-summary=1"},{"@key":"console.rows_per_page","@value":"user-summary=8"}]}},{"username":"rajan","email":"rajan@bizrtc.com","name":"rajan","properties":null},{"username":"+username+","email":"+email+","name":"+name+","properties":null}]
```

As I am very new to JAVA and JSP I don't know how to parse this data to HTML Table.

So Please help.

Comment: Use `JSONObject` to parse `JSON` data

Comment: Can u please put up a reference like @JyothiBabuAraja As i am new to JAVA and JSp

Comment: Must divide problem: 1. parse JSON to variable (object,  JSONObject is good) 2. Build HTML table with data. There is nothing like one-step parse

Comment: @JacekCz to use JSONObject do i need to add this to Java class file ? Or i can use directly in jsp pages ?? M being very dumb as i have a little knowledge with java and jsp

Answer (score 1):

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table) how to do it. You can populate it in Javasript or jQuery, but it is better to use JSTL and not just call java code inside JSPs.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use [mustache](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java) als template engine.

It allows you to use a HTML fragment as template (store it as resource) where double curly brackets (hence the name Mustache) denote the insertion points.

The full documentation of the Mustache syntax [is here](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) and a [Java example here](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java/blob/master/example/src/main/java/mustachejava/Example.java). Let us know how it is going.