# Javascript: Add Class to TD on dynamically generated table based on server data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below script that dynamically generates a table based on an array of objects that the server is feeding me that I got from [Here (hopefully I got the anchor tag right, here should be a link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

```
// Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data from Ivy restful service.
function buildHtmlTable(myList) {
 var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList);
  for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
     var row$ = $('<tr/>');
     for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
         var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];
         if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }
\\This is where I want to put the code that compares cellValue and applies 
\\the class
         row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
     }
     $("#Jsontable").append(row$);
 }
 }
function addAllColumnHeaders(myList)
{
 var columnSet = [];
 var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');
 for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
     var rowHash = myList[i];
     for (var key in rowHash) {
         if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1){
             columnSet.push(key);
             headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
         }
     }
 }
 $("#Jsontable").append(headerTr$);
 return columnSet;      
}
```

I cannot figure out how to add a class to each td based on comparing the value of cellvalue to a goal value where it is classed as .red if it is higher and .green if it is not.  My comment in the above code is where I believe the if/then should appear, but my kung fu is no good here.

Comment: I think you're probably looking for this: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue).addClass(cellValue > goal ? 'red' : 'green'));
```

Comment: The idea seems sound, but it is applying it to the whole row, not to the cell. As it iterates through I think it appends a td each iteration so I thought "$('<td>').last().addClass(cellValue > goal ? 'red' : 'green');" might do the trick, but no luck.

Comment: In that case, maybe: `var $td = $('<td/>').html(cellValue); if(colIndex == columns.length-1){ $td.addClass(cellValue > goal ? 'red' : 'green'); } $row.append( $td );` ?