# Parsing json one liner to html

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am a newbie here in JSON and need your input. I have a html file which loads my .json file

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function load_data() {
      $.getJSON("/data/rain.json", function(data) {
.....
       });
   }
   load_data();
```

where my rain.json file is loading the counts of raining days in the last month (30 days), quarterly and yearly

```
{
   "30 days": 1,
   "90 days": 17,
   "365 days": 80,
   "last_update": "2019-11-11 17:07:33"
}
```

How to I display this information in one row of the table with the header?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have
to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem
with your code.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11480797/2174170) a possible solution that might help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert json data to a html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through object entries to create columns and then add those to some table. Here is a pseudocode:

```js
const [th, tr] = Object.entries(object).reduce(
  ([ th, tr ], [ key, value ]) => {
    addTd(th, createTd(key));
    addTd(tr, createTd(value));

    return [ th, tr ];
  }, [ createTh(), createTr() ]
)

addRow(table, th);
addRow(table, tr);
```

You just need to implement `createTh()`, `createTr()`, `createTd()`, `addTd()` and `addRow()` functions =)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Object#entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [Template LIterals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

The idea is to transform your `data` into an array which is easier to parse and keeps things *dynamic*.

i.e.:

```js
const data = {
   "30 days": 1,
   "90 days": 17,
   "365 days": 80,
   "last_update": "2019-11-11 17:07:33"
};

console.log(Object.entries(data));
```

Then when you have an array (from your `data`) you can map through it and build your table.

Solution:

```js
const data = {
   "30 days": 1,
   "90 days": 17,
   "365 days": 80,
   "last_update": "2019-11-11 17:07:33"
};

const entries = Object.entries(data);

document.body.innerHTML = `
  <table>
    <tr>
      ${entries.map(([key])=>`<th>${key}</th>`).join("")}
    </tr>
    <tr>
      ${entries.map(([,value])=>`<td>${value}</td>`).join("")}
    </tr>
  </table>
`
```

Comment: I have a python script that dump the above { 30 days ...}.I am trying to generate the similar output as you shown earlier in the html inside the   <script type="text/javascript">
    function load_data() {
      $.getJSON("/data/rain.json", function(data) {
      const entries = Object.entries(data);
      document.body.innerHTML =
      <table>
         <tr>
            ${entries.map(([key])=>`<th>${key}</th>`).join("")}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            ${entries.map(([,value])=>`<td>${value}</td>`).join("")}
        </tr>
      </table>
       });
    } but no output