# display json data in a html table

Tags: html, json, angular, html-table, json-rpc

Basically what i have done is to insert some data to the database via the python server- werkzeug.
and another function to retreive those data from database. everything works fine with the result shown in the console of the browser.
now how to print those result which is in json format in a html table.
my code is very simple it does not contain any ngAapp or ngController.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-meta',
    templateUrl: './meta.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./meta.component.css']
})
export class MetaComponent  {
    res: any[];
    json;

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    public getall(){
    // alert('error');
        const data = {
            "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
            "method" : "getall",
            "id" : "1",
            "params": {'argument' : 'something' }
        };
        this.http.post('http://localhost:80/jsonrpc', data).subscribe( res => console.log(this.json =   
res.text()));
        // ...
```

HTML:

```
<button (click)="getall()">view</button>
<pre>{{json}}</pre>
```

the response i got in my html page after clicking the button is :

```
{"result": [["water", "None"], ["temp", "001"], ["temp", "002"], ["temp", "003"], ["temp", "004"], ["temp", "005"], ["temp", "006"], "id": "1", "jsonrpc": "2.0"}
```

How to display this data in a table in the html page?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_html_table

Comment: Hi @DaanSeuntjens i'm new to angular,can you be more specific where to implement this?

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with angularjs as well, but try to search online how you could tackle these problems. F.e. search for "angularjs json parsing" or "angularjs json tutorial example" or such and you'll probably find what you are looking for

Comment: Your json format is not valid. Could you please check once?

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table

Comment: <pre>{{json | json}}</pre>

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of json" >
      <td>
        <input type=text [(ngModel)]="i.result" >
     </td>
</tr>
```

*This will loop ur json data in table and u should alter the looping data as u need*
cheers..!