# Display JSON from API url into a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently trying to display JSON data as a table
in a web page: the raw data from the API url looks like this:

`{"body":"[{\"id\":\"67341472528\",\"name\":\"Dana Fin\"},{\"id\":\"87543263550\",\"name\":\"Jon Doe\"}]"}`

I was trying to use the jQuery/AJAX $.getJSON() Method and it displays the data  like this:

`[{"id":"67341472528","name":"Dana Fin"},{"id":"87543263550","name":"Jon Doe"}]`

but then I've been trying to put that data into a table for a while, I've tried a lot of things and  examples but nothing has worked.

so basically I was wondering if somebody has done something like this, thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Is there anything in particular you're stuck on? The general idea would be to iterate each record in that array, create a `<tr>` for each one then create `<td>` elements for each property with the values as `textContent`

Comment: I think that is you want
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table

Comment: Did you mean to edit out most of your content?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```js
// response from $.getJson()
const data = [{
  "id": "67341472528",
  "name": "Dana Fin"
}, {
  "id": "87543263550",
  "name": "Jon Doe"
}]

const table = document.createElement('table')
table.border = 1

// create header row for table)
const header = document.createElement('tr')
const idHeader = document.createElement('th')
idHeader.appendChild(document.createTextNode('id'))
const nameHeader = document.createElement('th')
nameHeader.appendChild(document.createTextNode('name'))
header.appendChild(idHeader)
header.appendChild(nameHeader)
table.appendChild(header)

// create entries for each response
for (const entry of data) {
  const row = document.createElement('tr')
  const id = document.createElement('td')
  id.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.id))
  const name = document.createElement('td')
  name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.name))
  row.appendChild(id)
  row.appendChild(name)
  table.appendChild(row)
}

document.querySelector('body').appendChild(table)
```

Here is a working [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mewitte-the-flexboxer/pen/wvaYGMq)

Comment: No need for the CodePen, you can run JS code directly in Stack Snippets. I converted your code, hope you don't mind

Answer (score 0):

Using a slightly terser syntax:

```js
// response from $.getJson()
const data = [{
  "id": "67341472528",
  "name": "Dana Fin"
}, {
  "id": "87543263550",
  "name": "Jon Doe"
}];

const header = `
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
  </tr>
`

document.querySelector("#data").innerHTML = data.reduce(( innerHTML, { id, name }) => (
  
  `
    ${ innerHTML }
    <tr>
      <td>${ id }</td>
      <td>${ name }</td>
    </tr>
  `
  
), header );
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table id="data"></table>
```