# Write REST API Response to HTML Table

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, rest

[{"employee_id":1,"employee_name":"rajan","employee_email":"rajan@gmail.com","employee_branch":"java"},{"employee_id":3,"employee_name":"rajan","employee_email":"rajan@gmail.com","employee_branch":"java"}]

I have the above response from API. how can call through ajax and display the employee list in html table.

I have tried but failed to get.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:9090/api/employees-list',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
         
      alert(response.employee_name)
        }
      })
    
      });
      </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert json data to a html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table)

Comment: I am not getting json data in ajax response but in postman I am getting response