# Generate .html files from json using nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm using Node.js for an automation work, I have JSON data and I want to generate html files from them after every interval. For example, I have a function which retrieves all the JSON data from database and now I want it to automatically generate .html files to a path from the given JSON data. How can I approach this ? Is there any node library or any examples to do it ?
This is my json:

```
[
 {
    id: '5ffee71aef57d4cf197729a5',
    date_checked: '2021-02-11T07:56:39.042Z',
    title: 'Notification with API',
    status: 'created',
    reach: null,
    sent: null,
    delivered: null,
    views: null,
    clicks: null,
    unsubscribers: null
  },
  {
    id: '5ffee71aef57d4cf197729a5',
    date_checked: '2021-02-11T07:56:39.042Z',
    title: 'Notification with API',
    status: 'created',
    reach: null,
    sent: null,
    delivered: null,
    views: null,
    clicks: null,
    unsubscribers: null
  }
]
```

Comment: You can simply create a model for the html then write to file using writefilesync as a string.

Comment: It would be nice if you also describe what type of html do you want.

Comment: I need some more clarity, what exactly you want to achieve? Is It something related to HTML table for just to prettify your JSON?

Comment: I have added the code to your answer. Just use ES6 syntax to append data into the html string

Comment: @SrinathKamath is there any reference or examples to achieve it ?

Comment: @MikeMalyi IT should automatically generate a .html with a table structure and the on every call it should generate a new file with date+name.html

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara IT should automatically generate a .html with a table structure and the on every call it should generate a new file with date+name.html

Comment: @prashantpadadune does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table answer your question?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara no i don't want to do templating , i want it to directly generate a .html file with table containing all the data's

Comment: You need to create a HTML template first which in turn could help you to pass JSON in that HTML and you can save it or transfer it to user. Because if you want to create a file with HTML extension, you need to follow the rules for to to be valid one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script creates simple html for your json
You can expand the columns array to add additional fields that you want to be in your table.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const columns = [];
for (let name in json[0]){
  if(!json[0].hasOwnProperty(name)) continue;
  columns.push(name);
}

const html = '<html><body><table><thead><tr>';

for (let item of columns) {
  html += '<th>' + item + '</th>';
}

html += '</tr></thead><tbody>';

for (let item of json) {
  html += '<tr>';
  for (let name of columns) {
    html += '<td>' + item[name] +'</td>';
  }
  html += '</tr>';
}

html += '</tbody></table></body></html>';
fs.writeFileSync(new Date().getTime().toString() + '.html', html);
```

Comment: this is awsome, how can i add styles to this also how can i change writeFileSync path to another director

Comment: For styles you can add attribute ```class``` or ```style``` to any tag, for example to ```table``` or ```td```

Comment: For different directoy use this code
```file.writeFileSync(path + new Date().getTime().toString() + '.html', html);```

Comment: The easiest way to add styles is to connect Bootstrap
```<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous"></head>```

Add it between ```<html>``` and ```<body>```
And then add class here ```<table  class="table">```

Comment: is there any clean way to do this approach ? this exactly what i want but i want to reuse this @Mike Malyi

Comment: @prashantpadadune sorry I did not get what do you mean. Did you try the last adjustments?

Comment: yes i added that but i want it to be more reusable, like the columns defined should not be hard coded and whenever i call that function it should give me a table of any json data @Mike Malyi

Comment: I edit my answer. Now column list gets from the first JSON object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228571/discussion-between-prashant-padadune-and-mike-malyi).

Answer (score -1):

I created a sample html model for generating html files.

`htmlkit.ts`

```
const { isUndefined } = require("lodash");

module.exports = class HTMLKit {

    data = [];
    curr_x = 0;
    curr_y = 0;
    fontSize = 'medium';

    constructor() { }

    x_pos = (spaces) => {
        this.data.push('&nbsp;'.repeat(spaces));
        this.curr_x = spaces;
    }
    y_pos = (lines) => {
        this.data.push('<div></div>'.repeat(lines));
        this.curr_y = lines;
    }
    text = (t_data, spaces, lines, fontSize = null) => {
        this.data.push(t_data);
    }
    td = (t_data, t_class = "") => {
        this.data.push(`<td class='${t_class}'>${t_data}</td>`)
    }
    tr = (action) => {
        this.data.push((action == 'start') ? '<tr>' : '</tr>');
    }
    tbl = (action, def = [], tbl_class) => {
        var thString = ``;
        def.forEach(th => {
            thString += `<th class='${th}'></th>`
        });
        this.data.push((action == 'start') ? `<table class='${tbl_class}'>${thString}` : '</table>');
    }
    wrap = (action, w_class) => {
        this.data.push((action == 'start') ? `<div class='${w_class}'>` : `</div>`)
    }
    setGlobFontSize = (font_size_index) => {
        const fontSizeArr = ['small', 'medium', 'large']
        this.fontSize = fontSizeArr[font_size_index];
    }
    getGlobFontSize = () => {
        return `<style>html, body, div, span{font-size: ${this.fontSize} !IMPORTANT;}</style>`;
    }
}
```

```
html.generator.js
```

```
const doc = new DOC();
const styles = STYLES.tr_styles;

doc.text(`<html>${styles}<body>`)
        data.forEach(el => {
            var p_mode = getPaymentMode(el.paymentmode);
            var t_type = getTransType(el.transtype);

            doc.setGlobFontSize(0)
            doc.wrap('start', 'container')
            doc.tbl('start', ["col-1", "col-2", "col-3"], 'tbl-class')
            doc.tr('start')
            doc.td('some data here')
            doc.tr('end')
            doc.tbl('end')
            doc.wrap('close', 'container')
        });
        doc.text(`</body></html>`)
        textData = doc.data.join('');

        fs.writeFileSync(f_name, textData, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            // console.log('HTML Generated')
        });
        return { "status": true, "error": "OK" };
```

```
html.models.js
```

```
module.exports.fd_styles = `<style type="text/css"> @page{size:8in 6in;margin:0}body{font-size:small;margin:0;padding:0}div.container{width:21cm;height:15.24cm;padding:0}table{column-gap:10px;padding:0 45px 0 60px;width:100%;font-size:small}th.dummy-8{width:8%}th.dummy-10{width:10%}th.dummy-20{width:20%}th.dummy-15{width:15%}th.dummy-0-5{width:20%}th.dummy-25{width:25%}th.dummy-30{width:30%}td{height:25px}thead{height:0}.details{position:relative;top:calc(70px + 20px)}.details-1{position:relative;top:calc(70px + 20px)}.details-2{position:relative;top:calc(70px + 15px)}.details-3{position:relative;top:calc(70px + 10px)}.details-4{position:relative;top:calc(70px)}.details-5{position:relative;top:calc(70px + 10px)}.details-6{position:relative;top:calc(70px + 15px)}.center{text-align:center} </style>`;
```

Comment: i didn't understood, can you share any repo reference or the structure

Comment: @prashantpadadune, I have made a model aka a class to handle the html tag insertions for a genric use. You can refer the ```html.generator.js``` to initialise the instance of the class and then use the ```doc``` object of the htmlkit class to create wrappers, tables or htm elements.