# How to make a simple catalog that is updated using external file?

Tags: javascript, css, xml, csv

I want to make product catalog, suppose 1-4 products in a row, and each product will be in a box with its details and price mentioned. I would like to be able to easily create the catalog based on a XML/CSV File which I can update.. Can any one point me in the right direction on how to achieve it. I am currently familiar with HTML/CSS.. I can pick up on Javascript if required.

Once finished the page will have a header, and then products displayed below.. I intend to print the page to PDF to share with other users..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should [read your file and load from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file).

Then once loaded, you [parse it into JSON object](http://techslides.com/convert-csv-to-json-in-javascript)

After this, you can [preview the contents inside the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table)
(this is important because we'll use this html table to generate the pdf)

Using the library [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) and it's plugin [AutoTable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) we generate a pdf file with the HTML table we generated previously.

This are the sample CSV file I used to test the example

```
Product,Price,Barcode
Sample product 1,100,802760000926
Sample product 2,95,802760000926
Sample product 3,20,802760000926
```

You can try it in my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rogeliomonter/2f9m0qse/

```js
let myList = {};
/*Function to load from CSV file*/
function openFile(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    var node = document.getElementById('output');
    node.innerText = '';
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        text = reader.result;
       //set to myList variable to be used later
        myList = JSON.parse(csvJSON(reader.result));
        buildHtmlTable('#output');
    };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};

/*this function generates the HTML table*/
function buildHtmlTable(selector) {
    var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList, selector);

    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        var row$ = $('<tr/>');
        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {
            var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];
            if (cellValue == null) cellValue = "";
            row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
        }
        $(selector).append(row$);
    }
}

/*Supports the function that generates the HTML table*/
function addAllColumnHeaders(myList, selector) {
    var columnSet = [];
    var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        var rowHash = myList[i];
        for (var key in rowHash) {
            if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {
                columnSet.push(key);
                headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
            }
        }
    }
    $(selector).append(headerTr$);

    return columnSet;
}

/*Converts CSV values into JSON object*/
function csvJSON(csv) {
    var lines = csv.split("\n");
    var result = [];
    var headers = lines[0].split(",");
    for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {

        var obj = {};
        var currentline = lines[i].split(",");
        for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
            obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
        }
        result.push(obj);
    }
    //return result; //JavaScript object
    return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}

/*Uses jsPDF libary to generate a PDF File from the HTML table*/
function download() {
    // Default export is a4 paper, portrait, using millimeters for units
    const doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.text("My List", 10, 10);

    var columns = ["Product", "Price", "Barcode"];
    
    //Here we use the id of the table
    doc.autoTable({ html: '#output' })

    doc.save("myList.pdf");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.5.6/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>  
<input type='file' accept='text/csv' onchange='openFile(event)'>
  <br>
  <!-- the HTML table that will have the csv table -->
  <table id='output' border="1"></table>
  <br>
  <button onclick="download()">Generate PDF</button>
```

Comment: are you using the sample data I provided or are you using different data?