# Create HTML table from JSON data with JQUERY or Javascript or ANYTHING

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert JSON array to an HTML table in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051061/convert-json-array-to-an-html-table-in-jquery)

I'm trying desperately to figure out out to make this table...

I have 3 fields I need to be in the same `<td>` and another field by itself in a `<td>`

I am successfully getting the data with JSON to my page with this code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'code.php',
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (json) {
    window.upc = json.upc;
    window.img_name = json.img_name;
    window.quantity = json.quantity;
    window.description = json.description;
  }


});
```

How can I get this data to be formatted like I want?

|TEXT|image|
|TEXT|goes|
|TEXT|here|

Comment: i don't think it is a duplicate, his data structure is different, and would probably take a bit of fanagling to use jqGrid as the answer to that question suggests.

Comment: @Devin:  Check out jquery.templ  it's a solid plugin (yes, only made it to beta, but it's good).   http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://icanhazjs.com/

**STEP 1. - DEFINE YOUR TEMPLATE**

```
<script id="template" type="text/html">
  <table>
    <tr>
         <td>{{quantity}}{{description}}</td><td>{{img_name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</script>
```

**STEP 2. - RETRIEVE YOUR POPULATED TEMPLATE:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'code.php',
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (json) {
     var yourTable = ich.template(json)
  }
});
```

You can append the variable yourTable to any element on the page.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't recommend ich at the moment as it seems to be using a version of mustache with a dangerously broken implementation of HTML-escaping. (The escaping in the current version of mustache is also broken, just not in a way that allows exploits.)

Comment: If the problem is the version of mustache, that is easily fixable...I've been using ich for some time now and have not run into the escaping issue.

Comment: What file do i have to include to use ich.template?

Comment: I also need it to be in a "while" kind of loop so i can display a random amount of entries

Comment: https://github.com/andyet/ICanHaz.js/raw/master/ICanHaz.js and yes you can do it in a while loop, just append the template to an object.