# Getting JSON data in HTML table

Tags: html, json

```
{
"error": [],
"result": {
    "DATA": {
        "asks": [
            [
                "622",
                "0.051",
                13
            ],
            [
                "626",
                "1",
                1385
            ]
        ]
    }
}
}
```

I am new in JSON reading HTML. Here is my JSON String and i want to read "ask" **array** and display it in Table.The type of getting JSON data from the server is **type: 'GET'**.

Please give me any sample example.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please show us your javascript code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert JSON array to an HTML table in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051061/convert-json-array-to-an-html-table-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After storing your Json data in a variable

```
var data = {.....};
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

you can access the asks array with dot notation this way:

```
var dataArray = data.result.DATA.asks;
```

then you can do whatever you want with the array in the dataArray variable.

You can also do this in the success function of your Get request, assuming that you are using $.ajax, here is a jQuery based solution.

```
$.ajax({
   type:"GET",
   url:"data source",
   dataType:"json", 
   success:function(data){
      var tableBody = "";
      $.each(data.result.DATA.asks, function() {
         var row = "";
         this.forEach(function(v) {
            row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
         });
       tableBody += "<tr>"+row+"</tr>";                 
     })
   }
})
```

The above example is to give you an idea on how to go over your array and add the data to the body. The following is a better option:

```
 var tableBody = data.result.DATA.asks.map(function(value){

    return "<tr>"+value.map(function(k){
        return "<td>"+k+"</td>";
    }).join("")+"</tr>";

 }).join("");
```

here you have only to append the string tableBody to the HTML dom in a div of you choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

this example is fetched from jquery.com , cosnider replacing list with your table

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/