# How to improve display of JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, styling

I am new to JSON and JS, and have generated a JSON file to display data via .onclick event. I have gotten so far as generating the JSON data and displaying it on screen, but now I want to style it in a table format, where the elements are able to be seen more clearly. Any help would be awesome!

Here's my JS:

```
    addEventListener("load", set_up_click_handler);

function set_up_click_handler() {
  var url = 'http://localhost/Advanced_Web/Final_Project/data/exhibitions.json';
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", click_handler);

  function click_handler(event) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.addEventListener("load", response_handler);
    request.send();

  };

  function response_handler() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      var json = this.responseText;
      var data = JSON.parse(json);
      window.localStorage.setItem('exhibitions', JSON.stringify(data));

            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.setAttribute("id", "dateOfExhibition");

      var list = $('<ul/>');

      for (var item in data) {
        list.append(
          $("<li />").text(item + ": " + data[item])
        );
      }
      $('#exhibitions').append(list);
    } else {
      alert('An error has occurred.');
    }
  }
    }
```

And if anyone is feeling extra charitable today, I'm also having this following issue: every time I click on my button, the list displays itself once again. How do I rework the code so that it only displays itself once?

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for your advice, I've edited my question.

Comment: OK, but it is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: @Paulie_D OK, thanks for your advice. I have been attempting what I posted for exactly 3 hours, testing different approaches ranging from styling the <ul> elements, creating <div>s that wrap around the list and styling those, researching on SO, Google, and watching YouTube videos. None of this has worked. My code is displayed above and is my most recent attempt. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you show an example of the json file you are trying to parse into a table

Comment: {
  "id": "Pavlov's Dog",
  "dateOfExhibition": "2018-07-08T22:00:00.000Z", 
  "address": [],
  "street": "Bergmannstrasse 29", 
  "city": "Berlin", 
  "country": "Deutschland", 
  "zip": "10473"}

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Convert JSON array to an HTML table in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051061/convert-json-array-to-an-html-table-in-jquery?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

without really knowing the style of the table required please see the example formatting the data into a table with the headers on display, the address with an empty array also has not been handled in this function

```js
var jsonData =  { "id": "Pavlov's Dog", "dateOfExhibition": "2018-07-08T22:00:00.000Z", "address": [], "street": "Bergmannstrasse 29", "city": "Berlin", "country": "Deutschland", "zip": "10473"};


function createTable(jsonData){ 
  //create headers
  var head = $("<tr />");    
  var keys = Object.keys(jsonData);
  keys.forEach(function(key){
    head.append($("<th>"+ key + "</th>"));
  });  
  $("#exhibitionTable").append(head);
  
  //append data (if you have multiple objects in an array like this wrap this in a forEach)
  var row = $("<tr />");    
  for (var item in jsonData){    
    row.append($("<td>"+ jsonData[item] + "</td>"));    
  }
  $("#exhibitionTable").append(row);
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  createTable(jsonData);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="exhibitionTable">
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The goal is to show the table upon clicking the button triggered by click_handler. So I assume I would have to somehow attach the click handler to the createTable?

Comment: on the response handler, you could have a div container for results, and inside the createTable function, create the initial table element and place it inside the container if the response is valid else show the error text

Comment: here is an example, using a container element to dynamically add the table https://jsbin.com/vutufaruxu/edit?html,js,console,output