# Convert JSON Response to (Bootstrap) table

Tags: php, json, twitter-bootstrap

I have a response from DigitalOcean's API to get the list of droplets.

```
{
  "droplets": [
    {
      "id": 3164444,
      "name": "example.com",
      "memory": 512,
      "vcpus": 1,
      "disk": 20,
      "locked": false,
      "status": "active",
      "kernel": {
        "id": 2233,
        "name": "Ubuntu 14.04 x64 vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic",
        "version": "3.13.0-37-generic"
      },
      "created_at": "2014-11-14T16:29:21Z",
      "features": [
        "backups",
        "ipv6",
        "virtio"
      ],
      "backup_ids": [
        7938002
      ],
      "snapshot_ids": [

      ],
      "image": {
        "id": 6918990,
        "name": "14.04 x64",
        "distribution": "Ubuntu",
        "slug": "ubuntu-14-04-x64",
        "public": true,
        "regions": [
          "nyc1",
          "ams1",
          "sfo1",
          "nyc2",
          "ams2",
          "sgp1",
          "lon1",
          "nyc3",
          "ams3",
          "nyc3"
        ],
        "created_at": "2014-10-17T20:24:33Z",
        "type": "snapshot",
        "min_disk_size": 20
      },
      "size": {
      },
      "size_slug": "512mb",
      "networks": {
        "v4": [
          {
            "ip_address": "104.236.32.182",
            "netmask": "255.255.192.0",
            "gateway": "104.236.0.1",
            "type": "public"
          }
        ],
        "v6": [
          {
            "ip_address": "2604:A880:0800:0010:0000:0000:02DD:4001",
            "netmask": 64,
            "gateway": "2604:A880:0800:0010:0000:0000:0000:0001",
            "type": "public"
          }
        ]
      },
      "region": {
        "name": "New York 3",
        "slug": "nyc3",
        "sizes": [

        ],
        "features": [
          "virtio",
          "private_networking",
          "backups",
          "ipv6",
          "metadata"
        ],
        "available": null
      },
      "tags": [

      ]
    }
  ],
  "links": {
    "pages": {
      "last": "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets?page=3&per_page=1",
      "next": "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets?page=2&per_page=1"
    }
  },
  "meta": {
    "total": 3
  }
}
```

How do I convert this PHP response to a (bootstrap) table?
I have looked at other solutions like [Convert json data to a html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table) but they don't work or dont use PHP responses. I would like the simplest way of doing this.

Comment: There is no "conversion" possible. You have your data (the JSON) and the support where you going to show your data (an html table). Here one approach how to DISPLAY a JSON into an HTML table -> http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/sewm6/

Comment: probably  you get answer here: [Convert JSON array to an HTML table in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051061/convert-json-array-to-an-html-table-in-jquery)

Comment: @DayronGallardo Hi I tried that before, I tried to put the whole response in like http://jsfiddle.net/sEwM6/4494/ but it just gave me object object, doesn't work. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so you have json response. First step is to use `json_decode` to get an array in PHP and then you can iterate through the array objects and render them in a table. This being assumed that you want to do this in PHP.

If you want the same in javascript, you can use angular js and use its template bindings to generate a table.

About being bootstrapped, it is just adding classes and not a very major change