# Iterate json elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My `.json`file is as follows:

```
{"Team1":
 {
  "Player1": {"minutes":"11:35", "tsr":"25.0"}, 
  "Player2":{"minutes":"24:44", "tsr":"53.8"},
  "Player3":{"minutes":"14:22", "tsr":"35.7"}
  },
 "Team2":
  {
   "PlayerX":{"minutes":"27:06", "tsr":"12.5"}, 
   "PlayerY":{"minutes":"04:54", "tsr":"27.8"},
   "PlayerZ":{"minutes":"03:21", "tsr":"33.7"}
  }
}
```

I want to echo a table, as follows:

```
 <table>
  <tr><td colspan='3'>Team1</td></tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Player1</td>
   <td>11:35</td>
   <td>25.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Player2</td>
   <td>24:44</td>
   <td>53.8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Player3</td>
   <td>14:22</td>
   <td>35.7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan='3'>Team2</td></tr>
  <tr>
   <td>PlayerX</td>
   <td>27:06</td>
   <td>12.5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>PlayerY</td>
   <td>04:54</td>
   <td>27.8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>PlayerZ</td>
   <td>03:21</td>
   <td>33.7</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

The number of players in each team is not fixed: it can be 3 or other number.

I am using jquery to refresh the `.json`file. This is the current (and bad) jquery code. It should be something like this:

```
var pdatafile = "json/pdata.json";
$.getJSON(pdatafile, function (pjson) {
    for (i = 0; i < pjson.Team1.length; ++i) {
        // Code
    }
    for (i = 0; i < pjson.Team2.length; ++i) {
        // Code
    }
});
```

Could anyone tell me how to make this jquery code works and how to print the table in jquery?

Comment: you can get some help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051061/convert-json-array-to-an-html-table-in-jquery

Comment: Rory McCrossan This is not duplicate, as the first part is how to access to the length of Team1 and Team2 number of players, that is, find out the number for the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a fiddle, say me if it's what you want :)

https://fiddle.jshell.net/ydwf5hks/1/

```js
let myJson = {
"Team1":
 {
  "Player1": {"minutes":"11:35", "tsr":"25.0"}, 
  "Player2":{"minutes":"24:44", "tsr":"53.8"},
  "Player3":{"minutes":"14:22", "tsr":"35.7"}
  },
 "Team2":
  {
   "PlayerX":{"minutes":"27:06", "tsr":"12.5"}, 
   "PlayerY":{"minutes":"04:54", "tsr":"27.8"},
   "PlayerZ":{"minutes":"03:21", "tsr":"33.7"}
  }
}

let html = [];
for(let team in myJson){
 let teamName = team;
 html.push('<table>');
  html.push('<tr><td colspan="3">' + teamName + '</td></tr>')
  for(let player in myJson[team]){
   let playerName = player;
    html.push('<tr><td>' + playerName + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].minutes + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].tsr + '</td></tr>');
  }
 html.push('</table>');
}

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = html.join('');
```

```html
<div id="content">
  
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see the fiddle. Does it work for you?

Comment: It works for me, i added a code snippet :) you can run it directly from stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(pjson.Team1).length; ++i) {
        do_something(pjson.Team1[Object.keys(pjson.Team1)]);
    }
```

Something like that should work

Answer (score 0):

```
var output="";
for(teamname in pjson){
  var team=pjson[teamname];
  output+=" <tr><td colspan='3'>"+teamname+"</td></tr>";
  for(playername in team){
    player=team[playername];
    output+="<tr><td>"+playername+"</td><td>"+player.tsr+"</td><td>"+player.minutes+"</td></tr>";
   }
}
document.body.innerHTML=output;
```

You could iterate with two loops and build up the html...