# How to Iterate a list of list data to fill html table in JQuery

Tags: jquery

**I have a table like this**

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
                <input class="form-control clsEmployeeId" id="txtEmployeeId" type="text" id="employeeId"  value="' + mainList.EmployeeId + '"/>
               </td>
               <td class="text-center">
                <input class="form-control clsEmployeeName" id="txtEmployeeName" type="text" id="employeeName"  value="' + mainList.EmployeeName + '"/>
               </td>
               <td class="text-center">
                <input type="button" value="Details" style="color: Red;" id="btnDetails" class="clsbtnDet"/>
              </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

What I want is to iterate a list and fill those fields and there is a secondary list of each row (Contains Employee Details) inside the main one and that secondary list data need to fill a modal which initiate by clicking the "Details "button.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: "*I want...to iterate a list and fill those fields...*" - can you share an example of that list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON array to an HTML table in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051061/convert-json-array-to-an-html-table-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .each() loop function which allows you to loop item(row) one by one at a time. It will passes the index (an integer) and the actual element that you can
use like the following.

```
function primaryTable(list){

    $.each(list, function (i, mainList){
      <tr>
           <td class="text-center">
           <input class="form-control clsEmployeeId" id="txtEmployeeId" type="text" id="employeeId"  value="' + mainList.EmployeeId + '"/>
           </td> 
           <td class="text-center">
           <input class="form-control clsEmployeeName" id="txtEmployeeName" type="text" id="employeeName"  value="' + mainList.EmployeeName + '"/>
           </td>
           <td class="text-center">
           <input type="button" value="Detail" style="color: Red;" id="btnDetails" class="clsbtnDet" data-detail="'+ JSON.stringify(mainList.DetailList) + '"/>
           </td>
      </tr>
     });
}
```

At the Button field you can pass a list through the data-* attribute which is used to store custom data.

After storing your secondary list details data, you could get that list in the button click event by the following code..

```
var detail_data = $(this).attr('data-detail')); 

var json_detail=new Array(); 

json_detail = json_detail = JSON.parse(detail_data);   // Parse list data as JSON
```

Then pass this "json_detail" list to a your modal function and use .each() loop onece again to fill up your modal.